# Why is VBA code creating partial duplicate records?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am running into an issue with my database that I think I know how to get around, but I am wondering if anyone can help me figure out why it's happening to begin with.

I have 2 forms that are linked together via patient id and MRN (patient home page and patient equipment log). When users enter a new patient on the patient home page, a new record has to be created in the equipment log form with matching MRN's in order for the new patient to be saved correctly and viewed later. When I click save on the patient home page, I have code that will check if there is an identical patient id in the equipment form and create the new record in the equipment log and fill in the linked fields with the appropriate information if there is not (see below). That part works fine.

```
Private Sub save_Click()
DoCmd.save
DoCmd.RefreshRecord
Dim crit As String
crit = [Patient List_ID]
Debug.Print crit
DoCmd.OpenTable "Patient Equipment"
qcrit = DLookup("[ID]", "Patient Equipment", "[Patient Equipment.ID]=" & "'" & crit & "'")
Debug.Print qcrit
If StrComp(crit, qcrit) = 0 Then
DoCmd.Close
Else
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "Patient Equipment Log"
Forms![Patient Equipment Log]![MRN] = Forms![Patient Home Page]![MRN]
Forms![Patient Equipment Log]![Patient Equipment.ID] = Forms![Patient Home Page]![Patient List_ID]
Forms![Patient Equipment Log]![Implant Date]=Forms![Patient Home Page]![Implant Date]
Forms![Patient Equipment Log]![Device]=Forms![Patient Home Page]![Device]
DoCmd.save
DoCmd.Close
End If
First_Name.Locked = True
Last_Name.Locked = True
Middle_name.Locked = True
Patient_List_ID.Locked = True
MRN.Locked = True
Device.Locked = True
Implant_Date.Locked = True
Transplant_Goal.Locked = True
Status.Locked = True
Caregiver.Locked = True
Address.Locked = True
City.Locked = True
State.Locked = True
Zipcode.Locked = True
Phone_1.Locked = True
Phone_2.Locked = True
Phone_3.Locked = True
Me.equipment_log.Visible = True
Me.echos.Visible = True
Me.open_logs.Visible = True
Me.edit.Visible = True
Me.openadvisory.Visible = True
Me.edit.SetFocus
Me.save.Visible = False
Me.cancelupdate.Visible = False
End Sub
```

When I enter a new patient, the correct corresponding record is created in the equipment log. However, a partial duplicate record is also created. A 2nd record is created in the equipment log containing the implant date and the device, but not containing any of the patient identification. I tried taking out these two lines of code, but the problem still happened and I'm not sure why.

```
Forms![Patient Equipment Log]![Implant Date]=Forms![Patient Home Page]![Implant Date]
Forms![Patient Equipment Log]![Device]=Forms![Patient Home Page]![Device]
```

I don't have a place anywhere else in my code where I add information like that. I think I know how to get around it (if statement to check if there's an entry in the equipment log without ID), but I don't know why this is happening to begin with. Any thoughts are appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I now know why it's creating a second record (the 2 problem fields actually belong to another table so a new record is being created). I have added the following code to fix the problem:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Patient Equipment Log", , , "[Patient Equipment.ID]=NULL & [Device]= Like 'h*'"
```

I'm having a lot of trouble with formatting this to run correctly. If I leave off the [Device]=Like 'h*', the form defaults to a new record. The device will always start with an h.

Comment: I just tried that, and it now won't let me save a record at all because I have a null value. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: It's throwing a flag at DoCmd.RefreshRecord, and the immediate window isn't printing crit or qcrit. The implant and device fields are from the equipment table in my query, so I think what's happening is a new record is being created automatically because I filled out 2 fields that technically belong to another table. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I still get "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Patient Equipment.ID]=NULL AND [Device]=Like 'h*"

Comment: I just saw your other comments. I tried the Is Null and still got the syntax error. [Patient Equipment.ID] is the name of the field in the query that the form is based on. (the query combines 2 tables, both of which have an ID field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this problem is much better handled by using a data macro than with VBA. I added a data macro to update the equipment log table when a new entry was added to the patient list table and set the desired variables in the equipment log equal to the values given in the patient list table. I now need to find a way to make the table update values when a new record is not being created, but that is a much cleaner solution to my original problem.